# how do I specify hashicorp/random version in my configuration?

Tags: terraform

When I run `terraform plan` or `terraform apply` the output includes this:

```
Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/azurerm v2.36.0
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/random v3.0.0

The following providers do not have any version constraints in configuration,
so the latest version was installed.

To prevent automatic upgrades to new major versions that may contain breaking
changes, we recommend adding version constraints in a required_providers block
in your configuration, with the constraint strings suggested below.

* hashicorp/random: version = "~> 3.0.0"
```

How do I specify version for hashicorp/random in my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify it in the provider block:

```
provider "hashicorp/random" {
  version = "~> 3.0.0"
}
```

Comment: In more recent terraform version, remove the 'hashicorp/' prefix and just call it random